# Drop Down list menu in excel

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu

I have created a drop down for 5 names. I would to have a list showing so when clicking for example on ABC a list will be shown for example John, David and James corresponding with ABC.

I don't know if this is clear enough.

Comment: Hi, Could you be more clear, like in which cell the list is , is ABC a button, and where you want the list to be shown.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44093232/copying-entire-another-sheet-column-using-dropdown/44094050#44094050